# Sanity Query Does Not Return Updated Data Consistently

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I have a "film" category in my Sanity database which has an array of comments.

In my UI, I present a pic of the film with the comments listed below the film. I created a function to add comments to the film and then fetch the film with the comments.

As you can see, in my addCommentToFilm function, I commit a patch query to Sanity to add a comment to the film; the commit returns a promise. I console log the response from Sanity, and it has the updated comments array (including the comment I just added). I then call a function to fetch the film from Sanity, but the film's comments array does not always have the last comment added: Sometimes it does, and sometimes I have to call the function a few times until I receive the updated array with the comment most recently added.

Does anyone know why this happens and whether there is a way to receive the updated list of comments consistently?

`

```
const addCommentToFilm = (filmId) => {
      client
        .patch(filmId)
        .setIfMissing({ comments: [] })
        .insert('after', 'comments[-1]', [{
          comment,
          _key: uuidV4(),
          postedBy: {
            _type: 'postedBy',
            _ref: user._id,
          }
        }])
        .commit()
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res); // I get the film with the comments, including the comment I just added
          fetchFilms(filmId);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Comment post error: ', error);
        })
  }

  const fetchFilm = (filmId) => {
    client
      .fetch(`*[_type == "film" && _id == "${filmId}"]`)
      .then((res) => console.log(res)) // I get the film with the comments, sometimes with and sometimes without the comment I just added
  }
```

`

Answer (score 3):

OK, received this information on the Sanity help thread on Slack:

This might be related to me setting 'useCdn: true' in my client.js file, as there is a slight delay between purging/revalidating.

Link to docs: https://www.sanity.io/docs/api-cdn#da702944cd86

Once I changed my setting to 'useCdn: false' the problem was solved, and now I am getting the updated data from the database in response to my query.

Great support from Sanity on Slack!

Comment: Brother you can't possible think how much you have helped me! I had the same problem with the comments data section. This usecdn:false saved my ass.